# pthread_atfork locking idiom broken?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, fork

The standard idiom for `pthread_atfork` usage is supposed to be to obtain all locks in the pre-fork handler, and release them in both the parent and child handlers. However as far as I can tell, this is impossible. `pthread_mutex_unlock` is specified to either have undefined behavior (in the case of normal or default type mutexes) or to fail (in the case of recursive or error-checking mutexes) if the calling thread is not the owner of the mutex. And in the child handler registered with `pthread_atfork`, the calling thread is the main thread of the newly created process, and thus *cannot be* the owner of the mutex.

Am I mistaken or is the whole `pthread_atfork` idiom broken by design and essentially impossible to use?

**Edit:** I also fail to see any valid (portable) workaround for the issue. Ideally one could just destroy and re-initialize the mutexes in the child process, except that calling `pthread_mutex_destroy` on an initialized mutex is specified as undefined behavior in order to accommodate ridiculous implementations where mutexes are not POD but involve a reference to some kernel-level object.

Comment: Also they tell you to re-create the threads **in the proper state** in the child. I fail to see how the stack and PC are going to be **the proper state** if you create a new thread in the child.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the relevant text from man:

> When  fork()  is  called,  only  **the
>   calling thread is duplicated in the
>   child process**.  Synchronization
>   variables
>          remain in the same state in the child as they were in the parent at
>   the time fork() was called. Thus, for
>   example,
>          mutex  locks  may  be  held by threads that no longer exist in the
>   child process, and any associated
>   states may be
>          inconsistent.  The parent process may avoid this by explicit
>   code that acquires and releases locks
>   critical to the
>          child  via  pthread_atfork().   In  addition,  any  critical threads
>   need to be recreated and reinitialized
>   to the
>          proper state in the child (also via pthread_atfork()).

The thread that executes atfork handler in child is an exact copy of the thread that executed atfork prepare handler in parent, and thus is entitled to unlock the mutexes.

Comment: I don't find this convincing. Being an "exact copy" (I put this in quotes because it's rather imprecise and doesn't appear in the spec) doesn't mean it's the same thread. Furthermore the semantics of robust and process-shared mutexes make it clear that the idea of "owner" for a mutex must not be a process-internal id that could be preserved across fork, but a system-global id...

Comment: Ultimately, it depends on how mutex stores its owner. If the owner is denoted by thread id, you are right - thread ids (at least on Linux) are globally unique. If the owner is denoted by a pointer to some thread header, then fork will do the right thing. I suspect the latter is the case.

Comment: At least for process-shared mutexes, the owner must be stored as some globally unique identifier. It would make sense to do the same for non-shared mutexes (just for consistency and simplicity of implementation), and in fact glibc/NPTL does use the kernel thread-id for this purpose. In any case, my question is more about whether this is a defect in the POSIX threads spec, so even if some implementations do "the right thing", it doesn't help and they might in fact be violating the spec by doing so.

Comment: I think that the language I cite tells us that the spec treats the new single thread in the child process as continuation of the thread in parent process that invoked fork() (for the purposes of locking).

Comment: Just tested with glibc, and the unlock in the child succeeds with default mutex type, but not with error-checking or recursive mutexes. As far as I can tell this matches the specification, which puts no requirements on the default type but requires the others to fail with `EPERM` when the caller is not the owner.

Comment: I agree with @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE here, I have been facing a similar problem myself. I have a recursive mutex and the atfork-child handler seems to fail to unlock it. If the thread was an exact copy, it should have worked for recursive locks as well.