# How can pthread_atfork make child process ensure lock state but not changing parent process lock state?

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix

I'm having some problems in understanding how can `pthread_atfork` make the child process ensure the mutex states. The manual tells me that use `prepare` to acquire lock before a child process is created and use `parent` and `child` to release the lock in parent process and child. Let's say, parent process `p` has a lock which is locked. And it calls fork after register those three fork handler. Both locks in parent and child shall be released, aren't they? But that would not be what we anticipate, right? The lock state has been modified in parent while we only want to change the lock state in child.

I've searched on google and also have also seen stack overflow. I find one problem[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473368/pthread-atfork-locking-idiom-broken] close to mine but that answer doesn't dismiss my confusion. I'm not sure if I've misunderstood the usage of the function, and can anyone helm, please.

Comment: Which _mannual tells_ you _that use `prepare` to acquire lock_?

Comment: @Armali Sorry... I actually see that in a book, not a mannual. And I've known how it works thanks to Employed Russian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say, parent process p has a lock which is locked. And it calls fork after register those three fork handler.

The parent process will *block* in the `prepare`, trying to acquire the (already locked elsewhere) lock.

If the thread which is trying to `fork` itself holds the lock, then that thread will self-deadlock, and this is a programming bug (`fork`ing while holding the lock is a no-no).

If *another* thread is holding the lock, the forking thread will wait (in `prepare`) for that other thread to release the lock, and then everything would be fine in both parent and child after the `fork`.

---

If you *know* that the forking thread (and not any other thread) has the lock, you *could* keep that lock across `fork`. In that case you would *not* try to acquire that lock in `prepare`, nor release it in either `parent` or `child`.

---

P.S. In practice, using `fork` in a multi-threaded program which you don't *entirely* control (i.e. a program which uses external libraries) is *nearly impossible* to do correctly.